# Button drawn above fragment element

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a fragment in my activity layout. When I click an item on it, it shows a submenu.
The submenu is showing but a activity button is drawn above it, while this is not what I want.

The button code is in a `RelativeLayout`:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoekfilter"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/lengterange"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="searchfilterbtn"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/zoek"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

My fragment code is located below the button-code in the layout XML file. Just above the `RelativeLayout`

```
<fragment
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.smartvibes.smartbeat.menuFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The "Zoek" orange button should be behind the pop-overmenu, just like the rangeseekbar and other elements.

[image: activity]

Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: For such purposes, you should use a PopupMenu (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I wrapped the button in a LinearLayout. Inside my initial RelativeLayout. This solved the issue.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/lengterange">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoekfilter"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="searchfilterbtn"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/zoek"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```